# How to use Skype2py API to call specific contact on skype by using username in python?

Tags: python, skype

I'm trying to make skype annoying spam bot and one of the features is possibility to call people, I know its useless and jerky but I'm making it just to learn how to code python.

So I wrote this:

```
import os, random, string, Skype4Py, sys, time

skype = Skype4Py.Skype()

def SkypeSpammer():
    value = int(raw_input('Enter amount of messages you want to spam: '))
    victim = raw_input('Enter skype username of victim: ')
    message = raw_input('Enter message you want to spam: ')
    delay = float(raw_input('Enter delay in between messages in seconds: '))

    for i in range(value):
            skype.SendMessage(victim , message)
            time.sleep(delay)

def SkypeCaller():
    skype.PlaceCall('skypeusername')


def OptionMenu():

    print '[x] What feature do you want to use?'
    print '[1] Skype Spammer'
    print '[2] Skype Annoying Caller'
    print '[3] Close'

    option = raw_input('Choose: ')

    if(option == '1'):
        SkypeSpammer()
    elif(option == '2'):
        print 'Still in progress'
    elif(option == '3'):
        print 'Closing...'
        time.sleep(0.1)
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print ('Invalid option, try again...')
        time.sleep(1.5)
        OptionMenu()


SkypeCaller()
```

As you can see in SkypeCaller I wrote simple command which calls username specified in () but whenever I run it nothing happens. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the attach call to connect the Skype object to the Skype client

```
skype.Attach()
```

try looking at this example https://github.com/Skype4Py/Skype4Py/blob/master/examples/callfriend.py

Edit:

The quick example given in the documentation for the Skype4Py module you are using (same github) is:

```
import Skype4Py

# Create an instance of the Skype class.
skype = Skype4Py.Skype()

# Connect the Skype object to the Skype client.
skype.Attach()
# Obtain some information from the client and print it out.
print 'Your full name:', skype.CurrentUser.FullName
print 'Your contacts:'
for user in skype.Friends:
    print '    ', user.FullName
```

It is not enough to only call the

```
skype = Skype4Py.Skype()
```

method at the top of your program you also need

```
skype.Attach()
```

So try adding the above line so it looks like

```
skype = Skype4Py.Skype()
skype.Attach()
```

Comment: I'm still begginer in programming so I dont quite understand what does those lines of code do exactly, I need better explanation :(