# Make automation in Skype using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I recently started leveraging Skype and use as Slack communication channel. I have build few automation in Skype but looking for quick extra things. I am looking for two things in Skype, 1. Trying to make a group/channel call as automated. Plan is to call a AWS Lambda script for this, but need a Python script which can make a group call. Currently I am using [SkPy](https://github.com/Terrance/SkPy/blob/master/skpy/chat.py)  2. Trying to tag everyone as `@all`, I have seen example [like](https://qxf2.com/blog/posting-messages-on-a-skype-group-channel-using-python/)  but don't know how-to?

Comment: Also, what have you tried? The example you have can be easily replicated for your needs.

Comment: I have two places similar approach running, one is 2.7 and one is 3.x. I think version doesn't matter.

Comment: @12944qwerty I can take care of versions. Yes, I have tried `ch.sendMsg('@all')` but it shows as text, not as tags. And for call, I don't see good approach to make it.

Comment: @12944qwerty I think this worked .... sendMsg("<at id=\"*\">all</at>", rich=True). Thanks ... Did you check for call? How to make calls?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35412154/how-to-use-skype2py-api-to-call-specific-contact-on-skype-by-using-username-in-p